# Compile or validate U-SQL programatically

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-data-lake

I have a requirement, where based on certain rules or conditions, the U-SQL script is generated. This is done via templating. I want some way to validate the generated U-SQL script, similar to the "compile script" feature in Visual Studio Code (for ADLA extension).

I found there are some references:
[Ref 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-sdk)
[Ref 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-data-lake-tools-local-run)

Would appreciate if anyone can point out how to approach this.

The choice of programming language is Python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to use it with Python(3).
The OS is Windows.
IDE used is VS Code.

Assuming all the extensions for Azure Data Lake ( and related extensions) already setup in VS Code, download the Local Run Service and Local Run Package.
Set the SCOPE_CPP_SDK env variable (with correct path) in Windows (no need to set it up as system level env, you can choose to set it as user level env variable also).

```
import subprocess

Local_Run_SDK_Path = 'C:\Users\batman\AppData\Roaming\LocalRunService\LocalRunHelper.exe'
Path_to_Usql_file = 'C:\\MyProj\Usqls\Create_Tables.usql'
Path_to_Dataroot = 'C:\\DataRoot'

cmd = [Local_Run_SDK_Path, 'compile', '-Script', Path_to_Usql_file, '-DataRoot',Path_to_Dataroot]
proc = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

assert proc.returncode == 0 # if successful, the usql compilation should return 0 to proc return code
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Lake Tools supports multiple custom codes. You can develop U-SQL with Python, R, and C Sharp for Azure Data Lake Analytics in VS Code.

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-develop-with-python-r-csharp-in-vscode) shows how to use Visual Studio Code (VSCode) to write Python, R and C# code behind with U-SQL and submit jobs to Azure Data Lake service.

For more details, refer [Extend U-SQL scripts with Python code in Azure Data Lake Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-python-extensions)

Hope this helps.